# How to extract inner property's type from a possibly undefined type

Tags: typescript, types

I have the following type

```
type User = { user?: { subscription?: {...} | null | undefined, ... } | null | undefined };
```

I want to get the type of `subscription`, i.e. I want to do something like

```
type SubscriptionType = User['user']['subscription'];
```

but TS Server throws the following error and the type of SubscriptionType is set to `any`

```
typescript: Property 'subscription' does not exist on type '{ __typename?: "users" | undefined; subscription?: { __typename?: "subscriptions" | undefined; id: number; activeSince?: any; renewalDate?: any; endingDate?: any; ... 7 more ...; } | null | undefined; } | null | undefined'.
```

I cannot define this type myself as it's being generated by graphql codegen and would change whenever the graphql query changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use the [`Exclude`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludeuniontype-excludedmembers) utility type.

```
type SubscriptionType = Exclude<User["user"], null | undefined>["subscription"]
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=6&ssc=80&pln=6&pc=1#code/FAguE8AcFMAIFUDO0BOsC8sDesCuyUB+ALm1kVwCNEBjFAS0lHoHsA7EsgQ1MVAbYBzWAF9YAH1htcAGxkS8bACbQAZvTbQlohdLkLcytRq2iA3GChwAylVoMmrNgBUrGWAFEAHjRm4VADxIqADaAET4qGEAugA0UrLykoYq6ppKAHzhFNR0jMzsMUA)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately I'm getting the type as never. It's my fault as I wrote down the wrong type in the question. I've updated the type in the question now.

The actual type was 

```
type User = { user?: { subscription?: {...} | null | undefined, ... } | null | undefined };
```

The `?` after the properties are messing things up. Without the `?` your proposed solution works perfectly.

Comment: I updated my answer. Does this work for you?